# fastest algorithm to count leaf nodes (i.e. terminal nodes)

Tags: trees, parallel-computing, counting, backtracking, subtree

With the following recursive code to count leaf nodes of a binary tree, is there any way to make it faster or parallel-computing optimized in time?

Python code - (mag(P) = number of leaf nodes of tree P depth H, left(P) = produces left  subtree and right(P)= produces right subtree, not given here, reduce the tree P to subtrees until terminal nodes are reached):

```
temp = 0
def mag(P):
    global temp
    if len(P) == 0:  #counts the one terminal node
        return temp+1
    elif len(P) == 1:   #counts the two terminal nodes
        return temp+2
    elif len(P) >= 2:
        return mag(left(P)) + mag(right(P))
```

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic here.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic" ?

Comment: To count the leaves, you *must* visit all non-leaf nodes, so there is little that you can earn. For a parallel implementation, you can use a breadth-first traversal on a few levels to generate enough subtasks. And it is likely that the speedup be mediocre.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. By dynamic, I mean dynamic programming modifications if any.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea of what you call "dynamic programming modifications".

Comment: @YvesDaoust Got it. I have edited it.

Comment: @Nathaniel where is the best place to ask this question?

Answer (score 0):

Store the tree in an array $A$ so that $A_i$ contains the index of the
parent's node. For example:

```
A = [-1 0 1 1]
```

would be a four-node-tree where the root node has one child and that
child in turn has two children. The root node has no parent, denoted
by -1.

Now go through all array elements in parallel. For every element,
increase a counter if its value is not marked and mark the value. The
counter now contains the number of non-leaf nodes and its trivial to
get the number of leaf nodes from that. Python pseudo code:

```
A = array of length N
M = [False] * N
cnt = 0
parfor e in A:
    if e >= 0 and not M[e]:
        M[e] = True
        cnt += 1
n_leaves = N - cnt
```

The `parfor` keyword stands for "parallel for" and runs its loop body
in $O(\log n)$ time (well-known result). This is probably as fast as
it gets.